# How to get daylight saving time with using pod TimeZoneLocate in Swift

Tags: swift, timezone, dst

I'm converting local timezone to string to display it on screen. For this purpose I use TimeZoneLocate library. Problem: I'm getting date result one hour less than it is because of not implementing daylight saving time.

I'm getting JSON from sunrise-sunset.org, and using this lines: sunrise = "3:22:31 AM"; sunset = "5:23:25 PM".

I thought about using function `isDaylightSavingTime()` with `if` statement, but I can't figure out where to add this one hour.

This is function where does the magic happen:

```
func UTCToLocal(incomingFormat: String, outgoingFormat: String, location: CLLocation?) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = incomingFormat
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

    let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: self)
    let timeZone = location?.timeZone ?? TimeZone.current

    dateFormatter.timeZone = timeZone
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = outgoingFormat

    return dateFormatter.string(from: dt ?? Date())
}
```

I use local "location" from CLLocation, TimeZone.current is provided by TimeZoneLocate library.

This is how I use it in code:

```
func parce(json: Data, location: CLLocation) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder() 
if let sunriseData = try? decoder.decode(Results.self, from: json) {

self.sunriseLbl.text = sunriseData.results?.sunrise.UTCToLocal(incomingFormat: "h:mm:ss a",
outgoingFormat: "HH:mm",
location: location)
```

sunriseLbl is printing the sunrise data from JSON for current location by default and for any place by GooglePlaces. But, in both, I get wrong date.

Also, here is a link to my project on GitHub, if it might help you help me: https://github.com/ArtemBurdak/Sunrise-Sunset.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give an example of your incoming format?

Comment: You need to tell us the exact values for `incomingFormat`, `outgoingFormat`, `location`, `dt`, `location.timeZone`, and `TimeZone.current`.

Comment: I'm getting JSON, and using this lines: 
sunrise = "3:22:31 AM";
sunset = "5:23:25 PM".

location I use local from CLLocation, TimeZone.current is provided by TimeZoneLocate library

Comment: How are you implementing this? Is this function called as an extension to the String type? I have tried to recreate this, but "self" isn't of type String, so `let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: self)` is causing an error.

Comment: Yes, it is extension for String

Comment: @ArtemBoordak I am currently trying to recreate this, but cocoapods is giving me issues.

Comment: @ArtemBoordak is the format of the string this function is called on something like this? `5:37:56 AM`

Comment: Okey, I am totally confused. Here is a link to my project on github: https://github.com/ArtemBurdak/Sunrise-Sunset. Please, if you have time, take a look. Thank you for your interest

Comment: @ArtemBoordak One thing that I noticed, is when setting `timeZone`, the TimeZoneLocate library is setting the incorrect time zone. The location I am passing in is CST, but `location?.timeZone` is returning EDT, which is an hour ahead of CST.

Is this the issue you are talking about?

Comment: @ArtemBoordak interestingly enough, `TimeZone.current` **is** returning the correct time zone, but `location?.timeZone` **is not** returning the correct time zone.

Comment: Well, probably you are right and problem is not in daylight saving but in location

Comment: @ArtemBoordak I think I've got a solution for you. Give me a few minutes here.

Comment: Could you clarify the *exact* value of `location`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting thing I noted: `TimeZone.current` **is** returning the correct time zone, but `location?.timeZone` **is not** returning the correct time zone. If there is a way to implement TimeZone.current, i.e. the application will always be using the user's current location, then I would advise using that. If users can enter a custom location, however, then you need to get a workaround for the apparent incorrect time zone returned by `location?.timeZone`.

My workaround is as follows. Notice that we manually adjust the location of the time zone we want by changing the `.secondsFromGMT()` property. This is how I adjusted your code, and it was returning the correct time zone for my personal location.

```
extension String {
    func UTCToLocal(incomingFormat: String, outgoingFormat: String, location: CLLocation?) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = incomingFormat
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

        let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: self)

        var timeZone = location?.timeZone ?? TimeZone.current

        if timeZone.isDaylightSavingTime() {
            timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: timeZone.secondsFromGMT() - 7200)!
        }
        dateFormatter.timeZone = timeZone
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = outgoingFormat

        let output = dateFormatter.string(from: dt ?? Date())

        return output
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** 
Time zones are very complex and change from place to place and from the current time of year. Just because this workaround works for my current location on this current day, doesn't mean that this workaround always works. **However**, you can look at the `timeZone.isDaylightSavingTime()` value returned as well as the current location to create a new time zone via `timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: timeZone.secondsFromGMT() - x` as needed. This is the way you can implement the

> "I thought about using function isDaylightSavingTime() with if statement, but I can't figure out where to add this one hour."

idea that you had.

**EDIT:**
For the record, the time zone I was using was CST, or Chicago time. The date I wrote this code at was April 19, 2019.

Comment: Strange thing. If I use secondsFromGMT: timeZone.secondsFromGMT() - 0, it works! If I don't use it or type another number, it shows wrong time

Comment: @ArtemBoordak that's great, but I would test that out from a number of different time zones and a number of different dates, to ensure that it doesn't just coincidentally work for your current time zone. You may need to account for whether or not the country uses some sort of day lights savings time, the time of the year, etc.